# Frequently change TextMeshPro text without garbage allocation?

Tags: unity

Is there a way to frequently change a timer display created with TMP, without it generating garbage?

I'm currently using TMP.SetText(), which is supposed to not generate garbage, but it does.

Comment: Have you tried TextMeshProUGUI elements and just use MyText.text = "text"? I'm a little surprised that your version generates garbage, if the documentation stated it does not. TMP is a really well done plugin. Can you post a screenshot of the profiler with the garbage part shown?

Comment: Maybe garbage is generated when you create these strings? Strings are immutable in C#, so every operation creates a new string, and unused strings become garbage. How do you create them?

Comment: As trollingchar says, if you want help identifying why your code is allocating and how to fix it, we'll need to see your code.

Comment: @iQew how could this be used without generating garbage when he's updating a timer? Assume the timer has sufficient digits that an array lookup of char array isn't possible. Is there a way to use TextMeshProUGUI.text such that it's not creating garbage in the way that SetText doesn't create garbage in builds? The answer with regards the question is answered below correctly. It's only in editor that SetText generates garbage, and because of what he's highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

What you could be seeing is, when running in the Unity Editor, TextMeshPro will allocate a string to display the formatted character array in the Inspector.  This only happens when running in the editor.  You can stop this by commenting out that line in the TMP_Text.cs file located in the project's Packages/TextMesh Pro/Scripts/Editor.  Like this:

```
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        // Create new string to be displayed in the Input Text Box of the Editor Panel.
        //m_text = new string(m_input_CharArray, 0, index);
        #endif
```

I am on Unity 2019.1.1f1, TextMeshPro 2.1.6.